# Magento refuses to upgrade 1.4.2.0 ===> 1.5.0.1

Tags: upgrade, magento

This is my first time using Magento.  I upgraded this site from 1.4.1.1 to 1.4.2.0 without issue.  Now trying to go to 1.5.0.1 it just seems to refuse at every turn.  I tried by entering this key into Magento Connect:
magento-core/Mage_All_Latest

And it says this:
Ignoring installed package magento-core/Mage_All_Latest
Nothing to install

I tried to upgrade via SSH and got this:
Attempting to discover channel "magento-core"...
unknown channel "magento-core" in "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest"
invalid package name/package file "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest"
Cannot initialize 'magento-core/Mage_All_Latest', invalid or missing package file
Package "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest" is not valid
install failed

In the downloader I noticed a the downloader had a version 1.5.0.0 upgrade available.  I thought maybe I needed the newest downloader before I could update all the packages.  I upgraded just the downloader to 1.5.0.0 which worked.  Then I tried the full upgrade again and now it is mega retarded with this:
Couldn't resolve host 'magento-core'

That’s cute isn't it?  So I gave it once last whirl at the ssh console and i get this bad boy:
Attempting to discover channel "magento-core"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "magento-core"...
unknown channel "magento-core" in "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest"
invalid package name/package file "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest"
install failed

I tried a forcing it via SSH but still no love.  I reverted from a backup I made so I do not have downloader 1.5.0.0 any more.  Now of course I am back to square one with it telling me there is nothing to install when I try to update via MC.
When I check in MC if there are any updates available it lists these two:
Mage_All_Latest Upgrade to 1.4.2.1 (stable) Metapackage for latest Magento 1.4 release 
And the Mage Downloader 1.5.0.1 but I already installed these before and it did no good so I restored my backup before the failed update.

I was trying to ask this question Magento's Forums but they are a mess right now.  Their captcha fails and threads close on their own so you get little to no help.  I wouldn't be surprised if they did this on purpose in concert with their 1.5.0.1 release.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade it manually? Not via connect?

Comment: I tried via ssh a couple of different ways as the question mentions (sorry it was so wordy).  Can you say explicity how you are refering to do to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the root of your website and execute these commands (Where index.php is):

`wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.5.0.1/magento-1.5.0.1.tar.gz`

`tar -zxvf magento-1.5.0.1.tar.gz`

Skip the next 4 commands if you have your magento install in a folder called Magento:

`cd magento`

`cp -rf * /home/bitscom/public_html`

`cd ../`

`rm -rf magento`

`rm magento-1.5.0.1.tar.gz`

For a detailed explanation see my post on the offical magento forum: [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219570/P30/)  My name is Veracious on there.

If your SSH account is anything other than your apache user (i.e.: root.  you will get error 500 when trying to access the site do the the permissions on the new files you just extracted.  To resolve that use chown and chgrp.  For a detailed explanation once again see my post:
[here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/220253/)

Comment: ty for the upgrade advice. it worked but all my custom css changes have been overwritten for the modern theame. any advice how to stop this happening in furture?

thanks Paul

Comment: Don't modify magento included themes.  make a custom theme, or take your copy of modern and name it something else so it is sort of like a custom theme and Magento will not overwrite it on upgrades.

Comment: This also works with 1.6.0. Try this solution **if all else fails**.

Answer (score 2):

I think the location for the upgrades have changed.  Instead of the: 
**magento-core/Mage_All_Latest** 
use: 
**community/Mage_All_Latest**

As what mrdon has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't upgrade through Magento Connect either. I followed these instructions for [installing magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh#installing_magento_with_the_full_download) and it worked fairly well. I changed line 3 as below to copy the folders/files over my existing ones.

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.5.0.1/magento-1.5.0.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf magento-1.5.0.1.tar.gz
cp magento/* magento/.htaccess .
chmod -R o+w media var
chmod o+w app/etc
```

Comment: What about the database??  They change the structure or content of the DB sometimes..

Comment: Well I was trying to fix a problem with magento and I thought the upgrade might fix it so I went ahead and did a manual install like you said. I did not use the cp command as you directed since I do not have my site in a folder called magento (it is on the root of the site). For people trying to follow these directions (if you do not have your magento install in a folder called magento) rather than typing that third command type: `cd magento` then `cp -rf * /home/pathYourExistingMageIsIn/public_html` (or type `cp -rf * ../` if it is just one folder up) lastly `rm -rf magento`

Comment: If you get error 500 fix your ownership of the new files with chown and chgrp. See my wordy instructions on that I posted here: [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/220253/)

Comment: I believe that database upgrades happen automatically when you upgrade the Magento core files - there are database versioning scripts within the core files that run when you hit a Magento page. I didn't have any database issues when I upgraded to 1.5.0.1

Comment: Thank you emily. yes it does update when you try to access the admin for the first time. Also the problems with Magento connect is because they switched to Magento Connect 2.0 and I don't think they have all their pear repositories in order. You can do a manual upgrade via SSH with my instructions here (veracious): [my update instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219720/) Also if you are having problems installing extensions:
[seeMyComment-Veracious](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219684/)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions from the following post to upgrade from 1.4.1.1 to 1.5.0.1:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/219720/#t301761

Then flushed the cache and reindexed everything. Everything worked.

Don't forget to change magento folder ownership to your web server user. In my case I had to run

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento
```